# Stripping Column or Row to Make 1D Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I want to create a 1D array from a 2D array without looping using only 1 line of code such as:

```
newvec = oldvec(:,3)
```

which in MATLAB would create a 1D array "newvec" from the 3rd column of "oldvec". My searching tells me the only way to do this in VBA is looping. For example:

```
redim newvec(ubound(oldvec,1))
    for i = 1 to ubound(oldvec,1)
    newvec(i) = oldvec(i,3)
next i
```

Is there a built in construct for stripping our entire singular dimensions of an existing 2D array to build a new 1D array?

Comment: You can copy the 2-D array to a `Range`, and then read the 3rd column of the Range to a 1D array

Comment: Thanks Shai but for speed, I prefer to stay in VBA and regardless your method will result in a 2D array with one of the dimensions having a value of 1 as VBA always reads data from Excel as a 2D array.

Comment: not really, read about Application.Transpose

Answer (score 5):

There is no builtin function in VBA for this purpose unlike most common programming languages. However there is a workaround using Index function:

```
Application.Index(MultidimArray, Row_Number, Column_Number)
```

> To extract a column from the source array, ‘0’ should be passed as
>   row_number argument. Similarly, to extract a row from source array,
>   ‘0’ should be passed as column_number argument.

So if you want to create a 1D array "newvec" from the 3rd column of "oldvec":

```
newvec = Application.Index(oldvec, 0, 3)
```

[Here](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/) you can find more.

**Edit:**

Using `For loop` is a lot faster than using `Index function`. So you better stick with `for loop`. See comments for details.

Comment: Thanks Tehscript. Does calling application functions appreciably slow down VBA over say just writing a loop in VBA? Since in this case, I'm dealing with relatively small data, I suspect not.

Comment: I did not test all of them but as far as I know built in functions work much faster than loops. For this purpose, I remember testing CountA function(to count non-blank cells within a range) against looping through the range (by checking cell values). Builtin function was considerably faster. I will have a look at index if I can, as well.

Comment: I'll take your comments on speed as good enough Thanks again.

Comment: I have just tested two methods. Unfortunately this time builtin function is slower than for loop. I've just test the required time for `newvec = Application.Index(oldvec, 0, 3)` and `For i = 1 To 1000000 newvec(i) = oldvec(i, 3) Next`. To get an average time I ran them 10 times for 1 million values. `Index function` took 14.56614 secs (average is 1.4566 secs) and `for loop` took 2.027344 secs (average is 0.2027 secs). So I advise you to go with for loop.

Comment: Tehscript you rock!

Answer (score 2):

Tested writing to a range then back as well.

Tehscript's post is correct.

On my test the `For` loop was five times faster than `Index`, 10x faster then writing to a range then dumping the third column back to a 1D array.

```
Sub Test()
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngCNt As Long
Dim dbTimer As Double
X = [a1:c1000000].Value2

dbTimer = Timer()
'test 1
'Y = Application.Index(X, 0, 3)


'test 2
'ReDim Y(1 To UBound(X))
'For lngCNt = 1 To UBound(Y)
    'Y(lngCNt) = X(lngCNt, 3)
'Next

'test 3
[d1:f1000000].Value2 = X
Y = Application.Transpose([f1:f1000000])

Debug.Print Timer() - dbTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: Then it's true, Loops rule!