# Reading excel row range as one dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

[image: Sample Excel Row range]

This above image is from an excel file row data. I want to read each cell from 1 to N cells as array in VBA

```
dim array() as Variant
```

I want output as

```
array(0)= 1
array(1)= West
array(2)= Product 9
array(3)= 15
.
.
.

array(N)= N column
```

Comment: [Try investigating before asking.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651439/11827059)

Comment: @ENIAC that code for columns values into array ,
i am asking for row values into array

Comment: A double transpose can pull that back into a 1d-array. e.g: `arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, x)).Value))` where `x` is the last used column

Comment: where x is not constant , N number of cells. @JvdV

Comment: `x` can easily be dynamic. Let me show you in a post.

Comment: @Siddhu, [there were earlier posts about rows also.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674957/11827059)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issues.
Thank you @Shyam i just modified your code little.
also I thank all other members who are all helped me.

```
Sub excelRowRangeToArray()
Dim rowNo As Long
Dim arraycell() As Variant
Dim LastColumn As Long

rowNo = 1 'row number which you want make as one dimensional array
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNo, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ReDim arraycell(LastColumn - 1)
For i = 1 To LastColumn
    arraycell(i - 1) = Cells(rowNo, i).Value
Next


'To check if your array has the required values, use this code:

For Each cellvalue In arraycell
    MsgBox (cellvalue)

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to extract the row 1, here is the code:

```
Dim array1() As Variant
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
ReDim array1(LastColumn - 1)
For LoopVar = 1 To LastColumn
    array1(LoopVar - 1) = Cells(1, LoopVar).Value
Next
```

To check if your array has the required values, use this code:

```
For Each cellvalue In array1
    MsgBox (cellvalue)
Next
```

Comment: your code some time executing correctly in some rows.
some case **LoopVar** prints **16385**.
I have three row
Example row2, row5, row7
each row values defined in different array variable. @Shyam

Answer (score 1):

You can double transpose your values into a 1d-array:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim x As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    x = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, x)).Value))
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I modified code for checking , if the row has only one entry then array shows error
'code'
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = 11
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("REPORT")
    x = .Cells(lrow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(lrow, 1), .Cells(lrow, x)).Value))
End With

'MsgBox x
For Each cellvalue In arr
    MsgBox (cellvalue)
Next
End Sub

Comment: Yes, if a single value is possible than a loop as per the other answer is a fine alternative @Siddhu.